# What is the equivalent of Windows' "AppData" in OS X?

Tags: windows, macos

I'm a long time Windows user and it's been week that I switched to OS X.

What OS X folder is the equivalent of the "AppData" (hidden) folder in Windows (C:/Users/userName/) ?

Answer (score 1):

The profile data is usually stored in ~/Library/Application Support

And the user specific settings are usually stored in ~/Library/Preferences

Comment: Is there an environment variable for that?

Answer (score 0):

It is organized differently, but `~/Library/Preferences` is analogous.

Further reading:

- [About Preferences and Settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Where are the Terminal settings stored on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63062/where-are-the-terminal-settings-stored-on-os-x)
- [Does Mac OS X manage registries for installed applications?](https://superuser.com/questions/55885/does-mac-os-x-manage-registries-for-installed-applications)
- [Where do OSX applications typically store user configuration data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410013/where-do-osx-applications-typically-store-user-configuration-data)
- [Mac OS X: Finding Where Settings Are Stored](http://www.westwind.com/reference/OS-X/finding-settings.html)

Answer (score 0):

No pun intended but you're comparing apples to oranges. `C:\Users\*user*\AppData` is a Windows concept. Some of that data will be in ~/Library, ~/Library/Preferences, or possibly other folders. For example, ssh keys and config will default to ~/.ssh. Even within any of these folders, you'll need to find the specific `.plist` file based on what you're looking for.

So the real question is "*Where do you want to go looking today?*"